# Can I integrate the gmail ubuntu webapp with a google apps domain?

Tags: webapps

I am trying out the webapp integration feature in ubuntu at the moment and am having trouble with the integration of GMail as a webapp using my Google Apps account.

When I sign into my personal GMail account in Chromium I get the pop-up bar that asks if I want to integrate it, I didn't say yes, I've just ignored it as this is my work PC.  However when I visit my Google Apps GMail account the pop up does not appear asking me to integrate.

I have successfully visited google calendar and google plus and got them integrated using my Google Apps account so why is the GMail element not asking on my Apps account?

Comment: integrations doesn't work with Google Drive either, it only asks on docs.google.com not drive.google.com

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug, just fixed last week, it will not prompt you to integrate with either google apps or gmail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

go to directory 
/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-gmail/

edit file GMail.user.js as sudo

find and replace this line

var gappslogin = document.evaluate('//div[@role="navigation"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ol/li[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span[2]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent;

you will get it working same as normal gmail account.

Comment: Welcome to AU. I'm assuming this was supposed to be a comment to Ken VanDine's answer and I've flagged it for conversion to one

Comment: Hi Journeyman Geek,  solution posted.