# How do I change the GMail WebApp account?

Tags: firefox, webapps, gmail, online-accounts

I entered in my GMail account and the webapp prompted in Firefox. I accepted and now, I want to change the GMail webapp account, but there is no option and, inside the "online accounts" from system config, there is no GMail configuration.
Could you tell me how to change account or delete them?

Answer (score 0):

See if Ubuntu Web Apps is listed here: https://profiles.google.com/connectedaccounts
If it is, remove it.

UPDATE:

Run the command:

```
dconf-editor
```

Find 'allowed domains' in `com → canonical → unity → webapps`

Remove mail.google.com from the entry.

Visit gmail again, using the new account this time, and it'll ask you again to enable it.

Comment: I have checked and there is no package unity-webapps-preview, and I have not installed unity-webapps.

Comment: @jchanam Please check the update.

Comment: Has anyone got this method to work with a business apps account?

Comment: @MarkFerree It works on Google Apps as well. If it worked for you, please upvote & accept the Answer. Thanks. Check this too: [Can I integrate the gmail ubuntu webapp with a google apps domain?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170422/can-i-integrate-the-gmail-ubuntu-webapp-with-a-google-apps-domain)